# Calculate Months between two dates?

Tags: formula, date

On quote whenever user specifies `Start Date` and `End Date` we need to calculate `Subscription Term` which should be exact months, here it should say `12 months` but its showing 11.96.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone please advise correction in formula or anyone having solution around it, so that I can calculate exact months between two dates(considering scenario of leap year in between)
e.g if `start date = 1 Jan 2000` and `End Date = 15 Mar 2000` then it should show something like `2.5 months` instead of `3`.

Formula we are using right now is following :

```
IF(

IF( SBQQ__SubscriptionTerm__c > 0 ,
SBQQ__SubscriptionTerm__c ,
(( SBQQ__EndDate__c - SBQQ__StartDate__c) / 30.4375)
)

= 0, 12,
(
IF( SBQQ__SubscriptionTerm__c > 0 ,
SBQQ__SubscriptionTerm__c ,
(( SBQQ__EndDate__c - SBQQ__StartDate__c) / 30.4375)
)
))
```

The reason we need exact term because the price which is applicable to products is based on term and we can't round of term as it will then lead to incorrect pricing calculation.

If anyone having solution using APex too , then it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You could just use YEAR and MONTH:

```
(YEAR(SBQQ__EndDate__c)   * 12 + (MONTH(SBQQ__EndDate__c)   - 1) -
 YEAR(SBQQ__StartDate__c) * 12 + (MONTH(SBQQ__StartDate__c) - 1) )
```

This should give you the correct result in all cases, although note that partial months would still be counted (e.g. January 31st to February 1st would be a full month).

Comment: Hey @sfdcfox thanks for your reply but for case 1 Jan to 31 Dec it will give  me 11 months and for case 1 Jan to 15 Mar it will give me 2 months as result

Comment: @NachiketDeshpande In that case, just add `1 +` to the beginning of the formula.

Comment: but partial months is still a concern even if I do 1 + to the beginning, it will still count a full month.

Comment: I used (date1 - date2) / 30.43685 , but gives inaccurate result for few scenarios , e.g 1Jan to 31Dec it gives 11.96 , not sure which number I should use to divide to get accurate result.

Comment: and for case of 1Feb to 28 Feb it will give me 0.89

Comment: What is the purpose of multiplying by 12?

Comment: @TemporaryFix I'm calculating the number of months from 0 AD, and subtracting the number of months from each other to determine the number of months. For example, 2/2021 is 24253 months from 1/1/0000, and 5/2021 would be 24256, and the difference between the two is 3 months (not including the end month).